# PIL Image to numpy array without copy

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to create an image as a 2D numpy array. The image pixel values will be 0 for the background, and 1 inside some polygons that I want to draw. I'm working with large images, so avoiding unnecessary data copies is important.

I started working with PIL image to benefit from the `PIL.ImageDraw` module.

Here is an example:

```
shape = (768, 1024)    # YX (rows, cols) convention
triangle = [(10, 10), (1014, 10), (512, 758)]   # XY convention
imgMask = Image.new('L', (shape[1], shape[0]), 0)  # XY
ImageDraw.Draw(imgMask).polygon(triangle, outline=1, fill=1)

mask = numpy.array(imgMask, copy=False)
```

Unfortunately, the last line always seems to result in a copy of the data. I suspect that the PIL array interface always returns a copy of its data buffer.

Is there any way to have a direct access to the PIL Image data buffer?

Comment: How did you determine that a copy was made?

Comment: I created a much larger image of shape (10**6, 1000), checked that my python session was using roughly 1GB of memory, then created my numpy array and checked that now python was using roughly 2GB of memory (linux `top` command).

Comment: You can draw circles and filled polygons etc with **OpenCV** which is very fast and uses Numpy arrays as the native image format already...

Comment: I am re-thinking my earlier suggestion - it is not clear to me how you can draw in-place with **OpenCV** as all the drawing functions seem to return a new array...

Comment: How complicated are the shapes you need to draw? Just rectangles and triangles? Or polygons and circles too?

Comment: Polygons for sure. Circles probably too.

Comment: I will have a look at this : http://www.silx.org/doc/silx/0.5.0/modules/image/shapes.html. Maybe benchmark it against opencv, see what is fastest.